# What is the difference between present simple and past simple in a past scenario?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, backshifting

In a group, we were discussing English grammar and academic writings. One of us wrote a sentence like this:

***She asked passers-by what they thought about New York city.***

A person claimed that this sentence is not contextually correct. It should be:

***'She asked passers-by what they think about New York city'***.

Because thought implies that they used to think in the past whereas think implies that what they were perceiving at that moment.

So, I was wondering which one is more idiomatic and logical. Or, they mean the same. Or, maybe they have a subtle difference.

Comment: “What they thought” is idiomatically correct. I guess it’s because the thinking she was asking about was the thinking that was going on at the same time as her asking. So, just as *asked* is correct, so is *thought*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The present tense would be appropriate for something happening while the sentence is being written or spoken:

> She asks passers-by what they think about New York City.

If the asking took place at an earlier time, then we put that verb into the past tense ("asked"). The person in your group suggested that "think implies that what they were perceiving at that moment." That is incorrect. In order to describe action at that past time, the verb must be [backshifted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_of_tenses) to the past tense:

> She asked passers-by what they thought about New York City.

Nevertheless, it is possible to use what is sometimes called the "timeless present" for "think":

> She asked passers-by what they think about New York City.

In this case, she asked passers-by what they think about NYC in general and not just at that time. (The Wikipedia page linked above calls this a "natural sequence" and says about it: "This option is more likely to be used when the circumstance being expressed remains equally true now as it did when the speech act took place.") However, unless you are very specific about which meaning you intend, there is not much practical difference between the two versions.

Answer (score 0):

I basically agree with MarcinManhattan, but let me say it in a different way. Maybe my way is more clear, or at least gives an alternative explanation.

In both sentences you say, "She asked ...", past tense. That is, the asking happened in the past. Therefore, any response that is reported must also be from the past. She could not ask yesterday and then tell us what they think today.

If you quoted her, then the quote would logically be in the present.

She asked passers-by, "What do you think of New York City?"

At the time she asked, she was asking what they think in the present. Well, probably. She could ask what they thought of New York City last year when such-and-such event happened.

That said, in English we also use the present tense for the "eternal present", for things that are always true. Like I might say, "Water freezes at 0 degrees celcius." "Freezes", present tense. I wouldn't say, "Water froze at 0 degrees celcious." That would imply that at some time in the past it froze at that temperature, but now it freezes at some other temperature.

So you could say, "She asked passers-by what they think of New York City", if you assume that they still think now what they thought at the time they were asked, that their opinion will not change. I'd say that's probably wrong because people's opinions about such things DO change.

Like if a pollster was asking about voting patterns, he might reasonably ask, In the last election, did you vote for the Democrat or the Republican? Past tense, because he's referring to one specific election that occurred in the past. He probably wouldn't ask, In elections, do you vote for the Democrat or the Republican? Present tense, presumably eternal present, implying that the person has always voted for the same party and always will.

But plenty of fluent English speakers would say it that way, so ... whatever.